# In Scrapy, how to loop over several start_urls which are themselves scraped

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to collect data on houses for sale in Amsterdam on http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/. The main page shows only a limited number of houses, and at the bottom there is a pager which looks like this:

[image]

("Volgende" means "Next" in Dutch). From this I infer that there are 255 pages in total. Each of these pages has the URL http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/p2/, http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/p3/, and so on. To get data on all the houses, I would like to 'loop over' all the subpages p1, p2, ..., p255.

I'm trying to see how I could 'set this up'. Till now I've written the following code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from Funda.items import FundaItem
# from scrapy.shell import inspect_response

class FundaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Funda"
    allowed_domains = ["funda.nl"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/"]

    le1 = LinkExtractor(allow=r'%s+huis-\d{8}' % start_urls[0])     # Link to the page of an individual house, such as http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49805292-nieuwendammerdijk-21/

    le2 = LinkExtractor(allow=r'%s+p\d+' % start_urls[0])   # Link to a page containing thumbnails of several houses, such as http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/p10/

    rules = (
    Rule(le1, callback='parse_item'),
    Rule(le2, callback='get_max_page_number')
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        links = self.le1.extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            if link.url.count('/') == 6 and link.url.endswith('/'):
                item = FundaItem()
                item['url'] = link.url
                yield item

    def get_max_page_number(self, response):
        links = self.le2.extract_links(response)
        max_page_number = 0
        for link in links:
            if link.url.count('/') == 6 and link.url.endswith('/'):
                page_number = int(link.url.split("/")[-2].strip('p'))
                if page_number > max_page_number:
                    max_page_number = page_number
        return max_page_number
```

The LinkExtractor `le2` calls back `get_max_page_number`, which simply returns the number 255. I would then like to use this number to 'synthesize' different `start_urls` for to be applied to LinkExtractor `le1`, which gets the links to individual houses on each page.

The problem is that as I understand it, `scrapy` processes these requests asynchronously, so I can't ensure that it will first get the number 255 and then use that number to generate other requests. If this is so I need to use two spiders in sequence and call them from a script, and in the second spider the `start_url` would have to be passed as a variable.

Any pointers on how to 'set this up'?

Answer (score 0):

You are over-complicating the issue here -- you don't need to know the max page.

Scrapy has url dupefilter so you can use linkextractor to extract all visible pages every time and scrapy will be smart enough not to visit the pages it has been to unless you force it.

So all you need here is two Rules with LinkExtractors: One that extracts all of the links and has a callback of `parse_item` and one that extracts all of the visible pages and has NO callback or `follow=True` [see docs here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=follow#crawling-rules)

Comment: Hi Granitosaurus, I'm trying to scrape all the pages "p1" till "p255". The main page only has some of the links in it: "p1" to "p7" and "p255". The other links only become visible after clicking "Next". So I don't see how I could scrape all the pages using only links on the main page?

Comment: @khpeek your `rules` apply to every page your spider visits. So the spider extract links from every page it visits as long as your linkextractor's `allow` attribute allows to which it does for in your case.